# Rails: Remove `validation_context` from object.to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to validate the user's input with my Model's validation.

First I parse some JSON and turn it into an object with validation.

```
rawactions = jsonresponse['actions']
rawactions.each do |a|  
 thisaction = Specialaction.new a 
 if !thisaction.valid?
 ...
 else
   actions.push thisaction   
 end
```

When I turn these `actions` back into JSON to send to the user for approval, I get these attributes in the JSON that I don't want.

```
    <%= form_tag '/applyactions', method: 'post' do %>                                                                                                              
      <%= hidden_field_tag :specialactions, Base64.encode64(@actions.to_json) %>                                                                                        
      <%= submit_tag "Confirm", class: "btn"  %>                                                                                       
    <% end %>
```

The JSON looks like:

```
[
{"action":"add","timestamp":"2024-02-05 10:00:00","validation_context":null,"errors":{}},
{"action":"add","timestamp":"2024-02-05 12:00:00","validation_context":null,"errors":{}}
]
```

I think the `validation_context` and `errors` shouldn't be there.

When I try to turn these JSON objects back into rails objects with my model and validation, I get this error:

```
  
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'validation_context' for Specialaction.

          raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self, k.to_s)
          ^^^^^):
```

This solution seems like a kind of hack:
`my_object.to_json(except: [:validation_context, :errors])`

What would be the correct *rails* way to do this?

Comment: Check this doc https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ArupRakshit could you please elaborate?

Comment: that linked doc if you read with examples, I am sure you need no more explanation from anyone to solve the problem you are into.